# The gbm (Generalized Boosting Model) function is not training correctly

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to use the "gbm" function to make predictions, although the program does not recognize me an explicit error, when using

`head (boos.model)`

and

`head (pred_boos)`

I am not having 0 and 1 as predictions, and I don't know how to fix it. I have tried with other models and up to the line `data.test = data [801: 1000]`, everything is fine. So I guess the error is in the lines that continue to that. My code is the following:

```
library("mltools")
library("caret") 
library("MASS")
library("MLmetrics") 
library("gbm")
library("mlbench")

data=data.frame()

for (i in 0:4){ 
  
  mu1=c(0+i,4) 
  Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2)
  X1_distribution=mvrnorm(n=100,mu=mu1,Sigma=Sigma)
  
  
  mu2=c(5-i,1) 
  Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
  X2_distribution=mvrnorm(n=100,mu=mu2,Sigma=Sigma)
  
  X=rbind(X1_distribution,X2_distribution)
  Y=c(rep(1,100),
      rep(0,100)) 
  data.aux=data.frame(Y=Y,
                      X1=X[,1],
                      X2=X[,2])
  
  data=rbind(data,data.aux)
}

data.train=data[1:800,]
data.test=data[801:1000,]

boos.model= gbm(form=formula('factor(Y) ~ .'),
data=data.train, 
distribution='bernoulli', 
n.trees=5000, 
interaction.depth = 4)

#head(boos.model)

pred_boos= predict(boos.model, 
newdata=data.test, 
n.trees=5000)

#head(pred_boos)
```